Is there a correct memory map for CVM-C10 power analyzer? I use modbus rtu using documentation from circutor memory map
Im working on a project using circutor power analyzer modbus rtu and raspberry pi and nodered. but some values of registers are not correct specifically the L1 to L2 V..is there a computations needed comparing to the displayed value?
I tried nodered modbus flex getter reading register.
sample
fc : 3
unitId : 1
address : 62
quantity : 2


but the value is different from display

Please tell us what value you are getting and what the unit is displaying (probably also helpful to show some of the other registers you are retrieving where the values are as expected).

Does this answer help? It shows how to combine two registers into a Float. Looking at the doc after combining the two sixteen-bit values, you'll need to divide the result by ten to match the display.

@importrandom the manual indicates that the response is a 32 bit integer (so multiplied by 10 and spread over two registers, but not IEEE754 floating point).

Or you could use MBPoll, an open source Modbus communication utility to try to read the registers, can be installed from piduino. The command line would look something like mbpoll -m rtu /dev/ttyS0 -b 9600 -a 1 -r 62 -c 2 -t 4:int -1 -B.  Substituting your correct serial port and baud rate. It's not clear from the documentation that the registers are big-endian.

Thanks @Brits, I'm not familiar with node red. It looks like the appropriate modification of that answer would be msg.payload = buf.readInt32BE(0);. Doc

OP said "some values of registers are not correct" which indicates that others are being read correctly. As such, until Bevin provides more info, I don't think it's possible to answer this.

I found it in the manual you have to combine the register bits like  data[62] << 16) | data[63]. thanks for the answers. cheers!

So I found this link https://flows.nodered.org/flow/4431eb891615ded1b3b4a980ad5f2ee0
you have to combine the 2 registers like in javascript
let line_voltage_1 =  data[62] << 16) | data[63];

